# Gradle task definition inheritance

Tags: groovy, gradle

Is it possible to inherit one task definition from another? What I want to do is create some test profiles, so I'd have default test -

```
test {

    include 'com/something/something/**'
    exclude 'com/something/else/**'

    maxParallelForks 5

    testLogging{
        exceptionFormat "full"
        showStackTraces = false
    }

    jvmArgs '-Xms128m', '-Xmx512m', '-XX:MaxPermSize=128m'
}
```

and some another test with overriden "include" or "maxParallelForks" part etc.

Is it possible without creating new Task class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could configure all those tasks in one go, provided they're of the same type using the following construct:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
  include 'com/something/something/**
  ...
}
```

This configures all the tasks of type "Test" in one go. After that you can override the configurations.

or if you don't want to setup all the tasks, or some of them have a different type, you can enumerate them as in the following snippet.

```
["test","anotherTestTask"].each { name ->
  task "$name" {
    include ...
  }
}
```

Remember, you have the full scripting power of Groovy, so there are a lot of options here...

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll go with your first construct "tasks.withType(Test)*.configure..." . I'm still curious though if there is a way of constructing some inheritance tree - to have some global test definition, then some testSuite1 extending global test, then some testSuite2 extending testSuite2,... I know there are some "hacks" how I can achieve this, though i would still like to see some nice DSL support for that.

Comment: The syntax can be simplified to `tasks.withType(Test) { ... }` and `task "$t" { ... }`. We believe that explicit *configuration rules* are a better approach than an inheritance mechanism with all its hidden semantics. Hence we don't have plans to add one.

Comment: Thanks for the simplifications Peter :)